# Web API 2 Generate Separate Help Page Per API Version

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2

We are making a versioned REST API using Microsoft Web API 2.  The versions are at different paths ("api/v1/...", "api/v2/...", etc.)  We're using attribute routing, with regex and range constraints for routes.

Using the [built-in Web API 2 help page generation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages) (or any third-party help documentation generator), how can we generate a separate help page for each API version?  It's acceptable if we need to hook into the help page generation mechanism (how?) to add custom processing, or to add hints to the documentation generator such as hint attributes or additional XML comment tags.